# Is there a way to implement lazy loading for kivy app using screen manager and only one kv file for screens?

Tags: python, kivy, lazy-loading, kivy-language

I have an app I'm developing with many screens, images and I am noticing launch time increasing as I go.  I would like to experiment with lazy load/optimization but not sure that it is possible with my current program structure.

I have one python file that passes all screen classes and WindowManager(ScreenManager) working with one .kv that has all my screen layouts, widgets/nav instructions.

Is it possible to delay some of these screens from being loaded without breaking up the kv file?  My goal is to decrease app startup time without sacrificing much performance so I expect trial and error but I am just not sure how to start.

Thank you very much for any of your time/help in advance.

Comment: If you are using `ScreenManager` you can use the method `switch_to` to load individual screen without loading them all at once, may be you can also somehow schedule them etc. It's all depend on you ui design. So post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If your `kv` file has a rule for each `Screen`, then your initial `ScreenManager` can be defined with just the initial `Screen`. Then you can implement a method to change `Screens` that chooses between setting `current` or calling `add_widget()` for the new `Screen` followed by setting `current` based on the return from `has_screen()`.

Comment: J.A.  This is what I was looking for.... seriously thank you (thank you AP coder as well I will try and do better next time).  So if I have all my button/screen navigations already set in the kv file, does it make sense to just switch this direction to set a dynamic variable instead and use that input to run the new method you mention in the python?  (screens are not straight line)

Comment: Not sure that I follow your logic, but the concept behind my comment was to just create new `Screens` as needed. Using the `ScreenManager` method `has_screen()` to prevent recreating  `Screens` that you have already created (if you always recreate the needed `Screens` you will lose any changes made to those `Screens`).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.